# Wordpress: Advanced Custom Fields not showing up on posts in front end after modifying theme configuration

Tags: wordpress

I installed Advanced Custom Fields and created a field group called "Apps", that shows up whenever a post is made under the apps category. IN that group is a "description" field. The field shows up without fail, or doesn't when the conditions aren't met, while making the post. However, after modifying the singular.php file in the twentytwenty theme to show the field on the front end, nothing changes. I am using the the_field function, like so:
**contents of singular.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying single posts and pages.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twenty
 * @since Twenty Twenty 1.0
 */

get_header();
?>

<main id="site-content" role="main">

    <?php

    if ( have_posts() ) {

        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
                    the_field('Apps_description');
        }
    }

    ?>

</main><!-- #site-content -->

<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/footer-menus-widgets' ); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I tried putting the the_field function as individual php outside the while loop as well; same result.
Is there something I'm missing? This appears to be what was laid out in the ACF function reference.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 1. I hope you aren't modifying the theme files directly. You should have a child theme - since any theme update will erase your custom work. 2. Is your field `Apps_description` or just `description`? If it's `description` that's what you should use. 3. You might want to put the code in the template part file (in a child theme) instead.

Comment: Hello! First, good call on the child theme, I forgot about that. I was modifying the default twentytwenty theme singular.php files. Second, I"m currently under the impression that the function reference states that the funciton alls for field group followed by field name, i.e. ``` the_field('Apps_description'); ``` has this changed recently? The field group name is Apps and the field itself is called description. Thanks!

Comment: No, it hasn't changed. You simply pass the field name. No need to pass the group.

Comment: Thanks, removing the fieldgroup worked!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this will most likely not help future visitors.